# repeater fields in sub option pages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I am having difficulties loading an acf_add_options_sub_page() fields in to context with Timber.

In my functions.php I have...

```
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Sponsors',
        'menu_title'    => 'Sponsors',
        'menu_slug'     => 'site_sponsors',
        'capability'    => 'publish_posts',
        'redirect'      => true
    ));        
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'National Sponsors',
        'menu_title'    => 'National',
        'menu_slug'     => 'national_sponsors',
        'parent_slug'   => 'site_sponsors'
    ));
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Regional Sponsors',
        'menu_title'    => 'Regional',
        'menu_slug'     => 'regional_sponsors',
        'parent_slug'   => 'site_sponsors'
    ));
```

In my template-home.php file, I have

$context['national_sponsors'] =  get_field('national_sponsors','options');

as per [http://timber.github.io/timber/#acf-cookbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTNm5.png)

But if I do a print_r($context), national_sponsors is empty, it doesn't even contain an object - just blank.

The fields are populated in the options page

[image: Screenshot of WordPress admin]

Any advice you can provide would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I see in the screenshot that you also use WPML?

Comment: Yes we do. This part of the site wont require translation, so we're fine there. But the ACF/Timber integration with WPML on template pages work fine in general.

Comment: I’m asking because we had a similar problem when we used repeaters in ACF options pages in combination with WPML. See this forum topic for more details: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/issue-wpml-support-using-repeatable-fields-in-option-fields/#post-35764. But you’re already using `get_field` instead of `get_fields`, so I guess this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't national_sponsors the slug for the options page? Should you not be using the custom field slugs?

```
$sponsors['facebook'] = get_field('facebook','option');
```

Or are you looking to get all the fields from a group?

```
acf_get_fields(id);
```

id being the id of the field group.